# Node.js asynchronous if statements GraphicsMagick

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to use the [GraphicsMagick](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/) library in my Node.js app, to manipulate images on the fly.

After the image has been selected using:

```
var image = gm('/path/to/image.jpg');
```

I want to perform several actions on it. The issue I am facing is because the actions to be performed come from variables. For example, if **blur** is true, it should blur the image. If **scale** is also true, the blurred image should then be scaled.  The trouble is, GraphicsMagic library is asynchronous, so this script would result in many actions being performed at the same time, which might turn out horribly.

<s>The functions do accept callbacks, as shown on [this example](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/blob/master/examples/blur.js) on GitHub. Although they appear synchronous, this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17769801/712410) confirms that they're asynchronous.</s>
New [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17745079) shows that the functions are synchronous.

How can I perform the actions on the image one by one, while staying non-blocking, when I don't know which actions are being performed?

I was thinking something along the lines of a NextAction() function which would be executed in the callback. The NextAction() would then trigger the next action, but I'm not sure about how to go about this.

I have researched StratifiedJS, but decided against it as I don't want to further complicate my app, and I don't think my PaaS supports it.

```
if(blur){
  image = image.blur(blur1, blur2);
}
if(scale){
  image = image.resize(resizeX, resizeY);
}
if(sepia){
  image = image.sepia();
}
```

Comment: Normally, asynchronous functions accept a callback function as a parameter. Those functions dont accept callback functions?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear. I believe these functions do accept callbacks. Edited question.

Comment: Looks like those are not async functions. The way you have written now is fine.

Comment: That's how they appear, but http://stackoverflow.com/a/17769801/712410 says otherwise.

Comment: It is actually wrong. I've made another detailed explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17745079/1312722

Comment: Thanks @Maksims Mihejevs, that's certainly cleared up my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GraphicsMagick** will not make any executions and work when you are calling methods on image like: resize, blur etc. an they are very lightweight.

In fact all they do - is adding arguments to the chain (strings to array of arguments).
So the object that `gm()` returns - is chain object, and does not do much until you will perform`write` method.

When `write` method is called it will in fact spawn process that all arguments will be passed to, and this is place where all calculation happens, and that is why it is async.

So in order to make your optional methods - you do exactly the way you need to do it:

```
if(blur){
  image = image.blur(blur1, blur2);
}
if(scale){
  image = image.resize(resizeX, resizeY);
}
if(sepia){
  image = image.sepia();
}
```

At the end `image` will contain array of arguments, and calling `write` to it, will execute all of them. Every time you call any of those methods which in fact you can have a look here: https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/blob/master/lib/args.js
All they do is return new modified object with added arguments.

Here is more details and explanation over this question and how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17745079/1312722