# How can I convert multiple colors with graphicsmagick and typescript?

Tags: typescript, graphicsmagick

I want convert some colors in a png Image with graphicsmagick. My code ist:

```
await gm("input.png")
    .fill("green")
    .opaque("blue")
    .fill("red")
    .opaque("yellow")
    .write("output.png", function (err) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    });
```

This work fine but it's hardcoded.
How can I develop a more flexible version i.e. by using buffer?

I tried this but it don't work:

```
  let colors: { op: string; fi: string }[] = [
    { op: "blue", fi: "red" },
    { op: "yellow", fi: "green" },
  ];

  let imageFileBuffer = await fs.readFileSync("input.png");

  colors.forEach(async (element) => {
    console.log(element);
    await gm(imageFileBuffer).fill(element.fi).opaque(element.op);
  });

  await gm(imageFileBuffer).write("output.png", function (
    err
  ) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  });
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the missing separation of image and image-processing. No await on image-processing is needed!

```
 let colors: { op: string; fi: string }[] = [
    { op: "blue", fi: "red" },
    { op: "yellow", fi: "green" },
  ];

  let imageFileBuffer = await fs.readFileSync("input.png");

  let image = gm(imageFileBuffer);

  colors.forEach((element) => {
    console.log(element);
    image.fill(element.fi).opaque(element.op);
  });

  image.write("output.png", function (err) {
    if (err) console.log("changeImageColors Error: ", err);
  });
```

Nice hints are:

- [Asynchronous GraphicsMagick For Node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17745079/1514029)
- [Node.js asynchronous if statements GraphicsMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20884281/1514029)